# Deploy production of create-react-app to heroku without buildpacks

Tags: heroku, create-react-app

I want to deploy my React project which was created with `create-react-app` to Heroku servers.

Simply pushing to Heroku causes the app to deploy in ***development*** mode.

(Maybe Heroku calls for npm start instead of npm build?)

I do not want to use any buildpacks to solve this.

What is the hands-on method to configure Heroku to build the app in production?

Comment: Please add some code so other users can test what you're describing. Thanks!

Comment: Heroku isn't a regular web host. It's not designed to blindly serve up static assets that you've compiled yourself. It's designed to run web _applications_ that get built during deploy using a buildpack. (It doesn't even offer a filesystem in a traditional sense.) If you just want to drop files on a web server and have them served up you'll have better luck looking elsewhere. There are plenty of services for that.

Answer (score 0):

First, set the production variable in the heroku cli:

```
heroku config:set NODE_ENV=production
```

Then, just change your package.json scripts to and you are good to go:

```
 "scripts": {
       "heroku-prebuild": "npm install -g serve",
       "devstart": "react-scripts start",
       "start": "serve -s build",
       "build": "react-scripts build",
       "eject": "react-scripts eject",
 },
```

With "heroku-prebuild" you can install the serve wihtout having to upload any additional code.